# why does my stream play correctly in jPlayer in all browsers except IE? 

Tags: jquery, flash, html, playback, jplayer

I am currently building a custom jPlayer instance for a streaming media file.
Having modified a supplied demo, I am able to get the player working in all major browsers except IE.

I have checked the swf path many times, which is loading without fault. I think I am unable to get the trigger to load the file in IE, resulting in "Attempt to issue media playback commands, while no mediaurl is set. Use mediaurl() to set. Context play()".

I am using an event trigger CSC class to play the media "track" in my source code (not mediaurl directly).

Below I will demo the current code, however I feel it would be more beneficial if someone could construct some pseudo code for me outlining the exact requirements to get this to work, and also an explanation of the GUI button CSS handles, so that I can get these working properly too (I may need to modify the JS, which is currently the standard).

I am using IE8 32 w/ Flash 8 and jPlayer 2.1.0

I only need the following functions:

Play button (jp_play?) - this should trigger the stream and then enable multiple other classes (jp_volume, jp_playline, jp_stop etc)

Stop button (to replace play button) - should stop (not pause) the stream and disable previously enabled classes.

If it helps jp_pause gives me all the required functionality with regard to hiding elements, except the mediaurl is paused, I need it stopping.

Thanks in advance.

Current code snippets:

```
// Instance jPlayer
    my_jPlayer.jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $("#jp_container .track-default").click();
        },
        timeupdate: function(event) {
            my_extraPlayInfo.text(parseInt(event.jPlayer.status.currentPercentAbsolute, 10) + "%");
        },
        play: function(event) {
            my_playState.text(opt_text_playing);
        },
        pause: function(event) {
            my_playState.text(opt_text_selected);
        },
        ended: function(event) {
            my_playState.text(opt_text_selected);
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container",
        supplied: "mp3",
errorAlerts: "true"
    });
    // Create click handlers for the different tracks
    $("#jp_container .track").click(function(e) {
        my_trackName.text($(this).text());
        my_jPlayer.jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: $(this).attr("href")
        });
        if((opt_play_first && first_track) || (opt_auto_play && !first_track)) {
            my_jPlayer.jPlayer("play");
        }
        first_track = false;
        $(this).blur();
        return false;
    });

});
//]]>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer"></div>

<div id="jp_container" class="demo-container">

<a href="**URL**/;stream.nsv&type=sound" class="track track-default" style="visibility: hidden"></a> 
<div class="buttons jp-play"><a class="jp-play" href="#">Play</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash version 8? You need at least version 10.3..